# Why Won't free() Work?

Tags: c, malloc, free, coredump

Im getting an error with free() every time I store input above the allocated space in the char*. Heres the error:

`*** Error in ./input': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09713008 ***`

When I remove the free(), the program runs perfectly even though I'm entering more than the allocated size. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it? Here is my code for reference:

```
int main(void){

  float x; // used to store the float the user entered.
  char c; // character used to check if the user entered a character after the float
  int loop=0;

  char * usr_input = malloc(50); //allocates memory to store the string from the stdin

  // loops until the user enters a float and only a float
  do{
    //gets the input string from stdin
    scanf("%s",usr_input);

    if(usr_input==NULL)
        printf("You've entered a large number that isnt supported. Please use at most 5 digits\n");

    // parses the input received and checks if the user entered a float and only a float.
    // breaks the loop if they did
    else if(sscanf(usr_input,"%f %c",&x,&c) == 1){
        if (x!=inf)
            loop=1;
        else
            printf("Input was too large. Try again");
    }

    // tells the user they entered invalid input. Loop value doesnt change so function loops again
    else{
        printf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
    }
  }

  while(loop==0); // condition for the loop
  free(usr_input);//crashes here
  return x; // returns the valid float that was entered
}
```

Comment: There is no `free` in the code you posted; please post the exact code that shows the problem

Comment: The code you have provided does not have "free" in it. It will likely be quite important where you are trying to use it, so you'll need to provide the code which *does* use free.

Comment: What's the point of allocating the buffer on the heap? It's small enough it can be on the stack and you'd spare yourself of all this dynamic allocation and release.

Comment: Also, `if(usr_input==NULL)` : this only happens if the `malloc` failed, which you should test before doing `scanf`. To check whether `scanf` succeeded, inspect its return value as you did for your `sscanf` call. Also, doing `%50s` instead of `%s` would be smart, as a buffer overflow could be the cause of your problem.  Using `fgets` instead of `scanf` would be even better.

Comment: And `char * usr_input = malloc(50);` should be `char * usr_input = malloc(50 * sizeof(*usr_input));`

Comment: @Biduleohm sizeof(char) == 1 is always true.

Comment: @Biduleohm Unnecessary -- the C standard mandates that sizeof(char) is 1.

Comment: @PeterSW Yeah but I bet AJPennster will use `malloc(xxx)` for a `struct` or a `int*` tomorrow and he will wonder why it doesn't work...

Comment: Actually, I knew that malloc allocates bytes and the size of a single character is one byte, thats why I didn't bother to use sizeof()

Comment: @AJPennster Ok, I made ​​a false assumption, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I remove the free(), the program runs perfectly even though I'm entering more than the allocated size.

Entering more than allocated size is called *undefined behavior*. This is an error, despite the fact that your program may appear to be "running fine".

The main problem with undefined behavior is that your program does not fail fast. Essentially, the penalty for having undefined behavior is delayed until some future time - for example, when you allocate again, or when you free.

`malloc` stores some special information in the allocated block that lets `free` run. The "nvalid next size" error usually means that your code has written over some of that hidden block of data.

To fix this problem you need to change your code so that it never writes past the allocated length. If you are having trouble detecting precisely the spots that need to change, consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or another memory profiler.

To prevent `scanf` from writing over your allocated size use the size in the format string:

```
scanf("%49s",usr_input); // Pass 49 for the length, because you have 50 bytes, and you need 1 byte for '\0'
```

Comment: I see. Is there anyway I can prevent that? Maybe by checking the size of the stdin buffer then allocating the amount of memory based on that size?

Comment: @AJPennster the answer is in Matt McNabb comment

Comment: @AJPennster Use fgets and sscanf rather than scanf -- that lets you limit amount read to the size of the buffer.

Comment: @Biduleohm Right - Matt provided a very good advise, except OP should pass %49s instead of %50s (he needs a spot for the null terminator).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Well spotted for the 49.

Comment: So the %49s for scanf will only alow it to take 49 characters? So i can use that? I forgot about fgets. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also, will I have to clear buffer after running scanf? What does scanf do with the rest of characters that are after the 49th character? are they left within the stdin buffer?

Comment: You really should read the man of `scanf` (`man 3 scanf` in a linux terminal or [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for example)

Comment: @AJPennster "What does scanf do with the rest of characters that are after the 49th character?" -- nothing; it has no idea what you want to do with them and it's not its place to guess. "are they left within the stdin buffer?" -- yes. As Biduleohm suggests, RTFM! :-)

Answer (score 1):

> the program runs perfectly even though I'm entering more than the
>   allocated size.

No, it does not run perfectly. In fact, the error you get is caused by writing past the bounds of the allocated buffer. Its a buffer overrun and introduces undefined behavior. Your program may work or may crash immediately, though in most cases it will cause problems later, problems that may look completely unrelated and therefore will be very hard to identify and correct.

Make sure you allocate a buffer large enough not to overwrite it.

On the other hand, it makes no sense for you to allocate that small buffer on the heap. It can be a static buffer on the stack and you'd avoid problems with memory allocation and release.